# Access dart embedded webserver from other devices on same network

Tags: dart, localhost, virtualhost, embedded-server

I am new to dart web and and now i am trying to access my web-page from other devices on same network .

When i enter command webdev serve , an embedded web-server listens on port 8080 and I can access that via 127.0.0.1:8080 on that device . but i can not access that from other devices on same network with `<DeviceLocalIP>:<port>`

In the past i tried to access Wamp VirtualHost from other devices and that worked this way . Please help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, webdev listens on 127.0.0.1 which is a special address that means 'listen on this device only'. To access your web page from another device you'll need to use the `--hostname` flag to specify the hostname or IP address of your computer, or you can use 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces, i.e.

```
webdev serve --hostname 0.0.0.0
```